# É possível usar coloração de vertices, arestas ou faces em um grafo DIRECIONADO?

Tags: grafo

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar a [técnica de coloração](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colora%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_grafos) em grafos direcionados? Se sim ou não, porque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, mas note que se existe uma aresta A → B, então A e B têm que ter cores diferentes, pois, caso contrário, A teria um vizinho (B) com a mesma cor. O mesmo raciocínio vale, mas ao contrário, se a aresta for B → A. Colorir um grafo dirigido não é diferente de colorir um grafo não-dirigido; por isso que ninguém distingue os dois casos.

---

Isso é diferente do que acontece e.g. no problema de achar a árvore geradora mínima: considere o grafo abaixo.

[image: grafo A → B (peso 1), B → C (peso 2), C → A (peso 3)]

Se o grafo não fosse dirigido, a menor árvore geradora mínima (no sentido se ser o subgrafo de peso mínimo onde sempre existe um caminho entre quaisquer dois vértices) seria obviamente composto das arestas A – B e B – C.

Dado que é o grafo é dirigido, no entanto, esse subgrafo de peso mínimo é a **arborescência** geradora mínima, que, no caso, tem que ter as três arestas 
A → B, B → C, C → A; para esse outro problema, o grafo ser dirigido ou não faz, sim, diferença.

Comment: Entendi, a minha pergunta foi justamente porque ninguém distingue os dois casos, obrigado!

Comment: mas e a coloração de vertices e faces, também é possivel?

Comment: Colorir faces é equivalente a colorir os vértices do [grafo dual](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafo_dual) (e aí vale novamente a resposta acima).

Comment: "Arborescência"?